# A logo on a T-Shirt printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to make this logo print-ready on a T-shirt, but I have a few questions:

1) I have an overlap in my logo, I tried to merge the whole artwork but I get conflation artefacts, I also tried the shape builder but the same occurs. I don't want the conflation artefacts and I also know I should't have any overlaps in the logo that will be printed on a T-Shirt. what should I do ? 
 [image: The overlap][image: conflation artefacts]

2) I have 5 colors in the logo (white, 2 blacks, 2 grays), I knew from the videos on youtube that I must convert them to spot colors to make a color separation. After that, I check them in the separations preview. I also know that white is not counted as a spot color, is that right? so now I will have only 4 colors as spot.

3) should the black be 0,0,0,100 as a spot color for T-shirt print?[image]
what about the other colors should they have a specific values or as soon as I change them to spot it's okay?[image: grey swatch spot color]
[image: second spot grey][image: spot black2]

4) I will save the file as High quality print PDF and leave the rest as default, is that correct?

5) If the client didn't mention which method he will use for printing the T-Shirt, should I still use spot colors, or I should make other file with Pantone colors so I cover all his needs?

6)if the client will use the sublimation method, is there any difference in saving method or colors?

Comment: Kinda sounds like it's less about rich black and more about just using the right type of paper. You should ask the printer for their input.

Comment: Thanks @Joonas So if I want to print this design on a T-shirt which black I should use ? I want is to look rich not dark gray or dull black.

Comment: what should I do If asking the printer is not an option ?

Comment: @New_spirit_designs you shouldnt be using CMYK colors if you print thison a shirt. But actually 2 different inks chosen for this purpose, espeically if you intend to silkscreen this.

Comment: @joojaa how I should't use CMYK colors and even spot colors used for T-shirts are actually CMYK colors. and what are the 2 different inks I should use? You mean rich black and white ?

Comment: @New_spirit_designs depends on how you print stuff. I can certainly instruct my t-shirt printer to choose exactly the inks i tell him to use. So you should choose a black that is properly black and not process black that is actually a dark gray. NOTE your printer MUST have the capability to print nonprocess colors as a a pure porcess color printer can not print white! White being a nonprocess color, if not then you can not print on any other color than white. But nobody can guide you on the formula of black that depends entirely on the printer, method used and look. Talk to your printshop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print on t-shirt just use black. Paints for garment are totally different from paints used to print on paper.
When printing on paper and you don't want to contact printer don't use CMYK black. Use Pantone. Or any other spot swatch from some makers.

Usually when contacting a printer is not an option (ie. you prepare logo for client for his later use) then it's no your problem. If you have no saying in choosing of paper, print method and so on then why should you worry about covering all bases. That's what Spots are for.

Answer (score 0):

This question as it is being asked can not be answered. There is no one rich black color, there are several. It all depends on what exact inks are being used, what method and how well the substrate binds the color. Also depends on what look and feel you want, as well as the used rasterization method etc etc.

In the best case scenario you can get to choose the actual ink formulation. If on the other hand your using some cheap digital press that is limited the what it is loaded then yes you need to choose a process color. Now what black they can print and with what formulation depends on the system, so your only choice is to talk to your printer.

If as you put asking the printer is not a option then you can not really make this choice. Its a stab in the dark and results are unpredictable even possibly going to ruin your batch. At the end of the day the person making final choice of materials and methods is going to affect the end results.

Or choose a printer based on capabilities you need.